# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am getting the following error after yesterday spring boot 2.0 update.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setContentNegotationStrategy' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:652) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:358) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:574) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:491) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751) ~[spring-beans-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:865) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:809) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:404) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:347) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:128) [spring-boot-test-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98) [spring-test-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116) [spring-test-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:102) [spring-test-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) [spring-test-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) [spring-test-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:243) [spring-test-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:226) [spring-test-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288) [spring-test-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290) [spring-test-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:245) [spring-test-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:189) [spring-test-5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283) [surefire-junit4-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173) [surefire-junit4-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153) [surefire-junit4-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128) [surefire-junit4-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203) [surefire-booter-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155) [surefire-booter-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103) [surefire-booter-2.18.1.jar:2.18.1]
```

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError

SecurityConfig file:

```
@Configuration
```

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Autowired
public CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().
            antMatchers("/secure/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')").
            and().formLogin().
            loginPage("/index.xhtml").
            loginProcessingUrl("/appLogin").
            usernameParameter("app_username").
            passwordParameter("app_password").
            defaultSuccessUrl("/secure/index.xhtml").
            and().logout().
            logoutUrl("/appLogout").
            logoutSuccessUrl("/index.xhtml");
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<groupId>miner</groupId>
<artifactId>miner-front-end</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>

<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <jsf-mojarra.version>2.2.11</jsf-mojarra.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf-mojarra.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>juli</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <addResources>false</addResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: the problem is with your dependencies, you probably updated something, but not everything you need. most likely, spring security was not updated, but core was, and it's not backward-compatible. for more detailed answer - add you pom

Comment: Just add pom file

Comment: I am getting the same error. It seems this happened in previous versions and it was fixed, but now the error reappeared

Comment: Is there any final solution for this question ?

Comment: The problem is in the dependency of spring-security.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is in the dependency of spring-security. Remove the dependency of spring-security-web and use only the spring-boot-starter-security. Also, don't fix the version of it and let Spring boot get the compatible one.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have the same problem and excluded spring-security-web from a parent inherit package and the error still exists. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've just removed and it's work again. I don't get it yet how.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a relational database with @Entity, check the primary key's @Id annotation in the model class.
It should be @javax.persistence.Id
not @org.springframework.data.annotation.Id

org.springframework.data.annotation.Id is currently used by Spring to support mapping for other non-relational persistence databases or frameworks that do not have a defined common persistence API like JPA. So, it is normally used when dealing with other spring-data projects such as spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-solr, etc.

javax.persistence.Id is the annotation defined by JPA for all its implementations. Keep in mind JPA only applies to the management of relational data.